# How can I make an algorithm environment wider than \linewidth or \textwidth?

Tags: algorithms, width

I have already tried two things: `\makebox[1.2\textwidth][c]{...}` which did not work (`perhaps missing \item`). `\redefinegeometry` does not work well in this case beacause it’s not on a single page. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{alg:euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$m,l$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of m and l}
\State $r\gets m\bmod l$
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
\State $m\gets l$
\State $l\gets r$
\State $r\gets m\bmod l$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $l$\Comment{The gcd is l}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Source: https://www.writelatex.com/examples/euclids-algorithm-an-example-of-how-to-write-algorithms-in-latex/mbysznrmktqf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make `algorithm` unfloatable and box it with another floatable environment which adapts the width.

In the following, an invisible `tcolorbox` is used for this purpose. Adapt the 
`grow to left by` and `grow to right by` options for the width needed. Also, the float settings are done by the `float` option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcolorbox}[blanker,float=tbp,
  grow to left by=1cm,grow to right by=1cm]
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Euclid's algorithm}\label{alg:euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$m,l$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of m and l}
\State $r\gets m\bmod l$
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
\State $m\gets l$
\State $l\gets r$
\State $r\gets m\bmod l$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $l$\Comment{The gcd is l}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If there are many algorithm boxes to be adapted, you could use the following variant where an environment `talgorithm` is constructed. It takes a symmetric growth value as mandatory parameter and any `tcolorbox` option as optional parameter:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{talgorithm}[2][]{%
  blanker,float=tbp,grow to left by=#2,grow to right by=#2,
  before upper={\begin{algorithm}[H]},
  after upper={\end{algorithm}},
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{talgorithm}{1cm}
\caption{Euclid's algorithm}\label{alg:euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$m,l$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of m and l}
\State $r\gets m\bmod l$
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
\State $m\gets l$
\State $l\gets r$
\State $r\gets m\bmod l$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $l$\Comment{The gcd is l}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{talgorithm}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `algorithm` is a floating environment and cannot be boxed.

But you can tell it not to float using `H` as a floating specifier (`\begin{algorithm}[H]`)

and use, for example, the `fullwidth` environment from the [`fullwidth`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fullwidth) package in this way

```
\begin{fullwidth}[width=\linewidth+2cm,leftmargin=-1cm,rightmargin=-1cm]
  <your stuff here>
\end{fullwidth}
```

In this case you're decreasing both the left and the right margin by `1cm`. Adjust the values to your needs.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{fullwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{fullwidth}[width=\linewidth+2cm,leftmargin=-1cm,rightmargin=-1cm]
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{alg:euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$m,l$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of m and l}
\State $r\gets m\bmod l$
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
\State $m\gets l$
\State $l\gets r$
\State $r\gets m\bmod l$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $l$\Comment{The gcd is l}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{fullwidth}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're comfortable to not let the `algorithm` float, then you can put it in a box that you can readjust to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,lipsum,changepage}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent\hspace*{-.1\textwidth}%
\begin{minipage}{1.2\textwidth}%
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{alg:euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \Procedure{Euclid}{$m,l$}\Comment{The g.c.d.\ of $m$ and $l$}
        \State $r \gets m \bmod l$
        \While{$r \neq 0$}\Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is $0$}
        \State $m \gets l$
        \State $l \gets r$
        \State $r \gets m \bmod l$
        \EndWhile
        \State \textbf{return} $l$\Comment{The g.c.d.\ is $l$}
      \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

For adjusting the width of the float in general, you can use the following preamble modifications:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,lipsum,etoolbox}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@algorithm
\patchcmd{\@float@Hx}% <cmd>
  {\@nodocument}% <search>
  {\@nodocument%
   \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{algorithm}=0 % Check whether using algorithm float
     \@algorithmtrue% Inside algorithm environment
     \setlength{\columnwidth}{\algorithmwidth}% Update column width
   \fi}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\renewcommand\float@makebox[1]{%
  \hbox{%
    % Adjust horizontally to give a centred look
    \if@algorithm\hspace*{-.5\dimexpr\algorithmwidth-\textwidth}\fi%
    \vbox{\hsize=#1 \@parboxrestore
      \@fs@pre\@fs@iftopcapt
        \ifvoid\@floatcapt\else\unvbox\@floatcapt\par\@fs@mid\fi
        \unvbox\@currbox
      \else\unvbox\@currbox
        \ifvoid\@floatcapt\else\par\@fs@mid\unvbox\@floatcapt\fi
      \fi\par\@fs@post\vskip\z@}}}

\makeatother

\newlength{\algorithmwidth}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\algorithmwidth}{1.2\textwidth}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{algorithm}[t]
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$m,l$}\Comment{The g.c.d.\ of $m$ and $l$}
      \State $r \gets m \bmod l$
      \While{$r \neq 0$}\Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is $0$}
      \State $m \gets l$
      \State $l \gets r$
      \State $r \gets m \bmod l$
      \EndWhile
      \State \textbf{return} $l$\Comment{The g.c.d.\ is $l$}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[2]

\setlength{\algorithmwidth}{.8\textwidth}

\begin{algorithm}[b]
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$m,l$}\Comment{The g.c.d.\ of $m$ and $l$}
      \State $r \gets m \bmod l$
      \While{$r \neq 0$}\Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is $0$}
      \State $m \gets l$
      \State $l \gets r$
      \State $r \gets m \bmod l$
      \EndWhile
      \State \textbf{return} $l$\Comment{The g.c.d.\ is $l$}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The preamble modifications includes patches to the float builder that is specific to the `algorithm` environment. The width of the float box is adjusted to `\algorithmwidth` (which can be set/changed throughout the document), again only while using the `algorithm` float.

Since the treatment of traditional floats and (non-)floats using a `[H]`ERE placement is completely different, the above-mentioned methods are exclusive. If you wish to combine them, you'd have to combine both methods. A non-float-ish alternative to `[H]` would be `[h!]`.