# Indentation of `then` in algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I've already benefited from `parbox` command to apply some indentation to some lines of my algorithm.

Now, I need to apply indentation to `then` keyword. As `then` is automatically generated by `\If` or `ElsIf`, I can not use the typical trick of `parbox` for that.

What I need is depicted in following figure: each `then` keyword must be aligned w.r.t. its corresponding `else if`:

[image]

My `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, conference]{IEEEconf}

\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx,algpseudocode}

\newcommand\Sth[1]{S^{#1}\mkern-3mu(\mkern-2.5mu\theta^{\mkern-1mu#1}\mkern-2mu)}

\title{My Title*}

\author{Guy$^{1}$
    \thanks{*This work was not supported by any organization}
    \thanks{$^{1}$Guy is with Hell, {\tt\small guy@hell.edu}}
}

\algnewcommand\algorithmicforeach{\textbf{for each}}
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForEach}[1]{\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}

\let\oldReturn\Return
\renewcommand{\Return}{\State\oldReturn}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{abstract}

        ABSTRACT

    \end{abstract}

    \section{INTRODUCTION}

    \begin{algorithm}
        \renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}
        \caption{algorithm}
        \label{euclid}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
            \While{true}
            \ForEach{xxx}
            \State do $A$
            \If{nothing happened}
            \State \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\algorithmicindent}{$\text{updated var} \gets \varnothing$\strut}
            \ElsIf{objects lie inside the same operating space}
            \ForEach{object with sweeping function $S$}
            \State \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\algorithmicindent}{$\text{updated var} \gets S$\strut}  
            \EndFor
            \ElsIf{objects lie inside different operating space} 
            \ForAll{functions $B$}
            \ForAll{functions $C$}
            \State \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\algorithmicindent}{$\text{updated adjacency} \gets S$\strut}
            \EndFor
            \EndFor
            \EndIf
            \Return updated var
            \EndFor  
            \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

- There are no line numbers where `then` is - this is an indicator that this is not an own logical line.
- It's just a line break because the text is too long in order to fit in one line.
- I used a very small font size to show you where the logical line breaks occur.
- You use a documentclass with two columns -- therefore the text width is pretty small.

[image]

[image]

(I used [Show frame/margin in two column layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271285/) to show the borders.)

### Related Links Regarding the Width of the `algorithm` Environment

- [Set width of algorithm environment (preferably document wide)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7484)
- [Adjust width of algorithm float](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350434)
- [How can I make an algorithm environment wider than \linewidth or \textwidth?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215274)

Comment: I can't increase the column width, which is something fixed by the conference. On the other hand, decreasing the font size will considerably decrease the readability. I'm wondering whether there is any macro to apply some degrees of freedom to placement of `then` and its indentation.